# Wrapping or removing parts of a <span> by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically created span that I want to remove partly or target partly by CSS. Basically it goes like that:

```
<span class="myOuterClass">
 <span class="myInnerClass">...some text</span><!--.myInnerClass-->
   some more text/10
</span><!--myOuterClass-->
```

I want to remove the last three characters /10.

My ideas are:

1. Wrapping these characters in another span (using jQuery), giving the span a class (e.g. new_class) and remove it by using CSS.

```
.new_class {display: none;}
```

2. Or using jQuery to remove the last three characters.

Both methods are OK for me, but I cannot do both of them it due to my poor jQuery.
Can anybody give me some ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove 3 characters in innerHtml:

```
$('.myOuterClass').each((index,item)=>{
  const itemHtml = $(item).html()
  $(item).html(itemHtml.substring(0,itemHtml.length - 4))
})
```

See full example in the playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/0cu64jLs/10/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Do you have a link about the syntax that is used, so I can learn more about that topic?

Comment: I use three simple part. First, I select all items with class selector `$('.myOuterClass')`. Then I take every item in loop `.each` and in callback function I trim last three characters. You can use this links for more information: https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ https://api.jquery.com/each/ https://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

Either way would work.

1.

```
<span class="myOuterClass">
 <span class="myInnerClass">...some t<span class="threeLastCharacters">ext</span></span><!--.myInnerClass-->
   some more text/10
</span><!--myOuterClass-->
```

Then on a click or however you want to activate it you would do

```
$('.threeLastCharacters').css('display', 'none');
```

2. 

You can retrieve the text from the span, or even better if it was dynamically generated you could store it somewhere when generated (a variable or data()).

```
 <span class="myInnerClass">...some text</span><!--.myInnerClass-->
   some more text/10
</span><!--myOuterClass-->
```

Then you can have a function:

```
function removeLastThree() {
   const myString = $('.myInnerClass).text();   //myString === '...some text'
   const substring = myString.substring(0, myString.length - 3);  //substring === '...some t';
   $('.myInnerClass).text(substring);   //this will now change the text in the <span> to the text without the last three letters.
```